# Cannot set metadata on a Google Storage Object from Node.js using Firebase Admin

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am writing a Firebase app and I need to change something in the backend running Node.js

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  storageBucket: config.get("firebase.storage")
});
```

I get the bucket from initializing admin and am able to see the existing metadata from that file. Setting it doesn't work:

```
const myfile = {URL: "/users/1/demo.png"}; //this file exists

const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
const [metadata] = await bucket.file(redeemable.URL).getMetadata();
console.log(metadata); //this works
if (!metadata.metadata.whitelist) metadata.metadata.whitelist = {};

metadata.metadata.whitelist[req.user.userId] = true;

await bucket.file(myfile.URL).setMetadata(metadata);
```

Shouldn't the firebase admin have access rights? I also don't get any error.

Comment: There's too much missing information here.  What exactly doesn't work?  Is there an error?  What are the values of all the variables in here that we can't see?  Try hardcoding values instead so we can see what you intend to do.

Comment: setMetadata does not work. bucket and file (the only variables) are correct I can see and console.log the file's metadata but when I set it, it doesn't. It is also missing from the official docs. No error

Comment: Metadata does work.  Without seeing all the exact values you're dealing with, there's nothing Stack Overflow can do do help.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am very sorry to hear with authority that you are sure it works and that SO cannot  help. Can you tell me what exact values do you need? The file string? I can never produce an example that works simply because it needs my access codes to my google storage server which cannot be published. Nothing else is missing. But it *is* missing from their official docs for Node.js and only mentions setting metadata from the gsutil tool. I did add more code to make it clearer.

Comment: When you say `console.log(metadata)` works, what exactly does it do that meets your expectations?  What exactly does the object look like that you're passing to setMetadata? Let's distill this code down to a single call to setMetadata to see if it receives the data you expect.

Comment: console.log sends back { name, url, otherproperties, metadata: { someproperty: somevalue } }. After setMetadata with a new object that added a second property after someproperty, and subsequently call console.log the extra property is not set but there is no error anywhere in the process.

Comment: And if you eliminate all variables by calling setMetadata with a hard-coded object, as prompted by the API documentation?

Comment: interesting. the metadata is not set because it can only be a property and not a nested object or array as I was trying to set. It's nowhere written in the docs but I could have thought about this since it's supposed to be just "properties".

Answer (score 4):

As the OP figured out in the comments, `metadata` object must be of type `{ metadata: Record<string, string> }`. The [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#setMetadata) doesn't mention this, and the TypeScript typings do not help either.

EDIT: the docs *do* actually mention it (emphasis mine):

> You can set custom key/value pairs in the **metadata key** of the given object,

but the wording makes it is easy to miss.

```js
bucket
    .file("path/to/file")
    .setMetadata({
      metadata: {
        someKey: "someValue",
      },
    })
```